# Roots of $x^{4} -28 x^{2}+49$ with Horner

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am studying Horner's algorithm and I got a problem I can't solve.

The polynomal is $x^{4} -28 x^{2}+49$. After trying $\pm 1, \pm 7, \pm49$ with Horner I couldn't find any solution. Wolfram alpha gives solutions that include squares and I can't see how could I come to such solution. What's could be my next step?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Set y=x^2 and you'll get a quadratic

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $u = x^{2}$ if you make this change you will have:

$$u^{2} - 28 u +49$$

from here you can use the quadratic formula to factorize it and solve it, when you solve it  for $u$ remember to go back to $x$

Comment: Okay I understand that, but this exercise is under the exercises for Horner. Is there no way to solve it with Horner? I got a similar one where I am stuck: x^5 - x^3 + 3x^2 -3. I get to first two roots x=1 and x=-1, but I can't find the third one which is according to wolfram alpha - thirdsquareroot(3). How the hell do I find this one?

Answer (score 0):

Put $x^2=y$   now the equation becomes quadratic so solve for y. Then after getting two roots now substitute $x^2$ in place of y and again solve for x and get the roots of the given polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a case like this is fairly easy. These are in fact known as biquadratic equations, or in other words when you have only $x^4$, $x^2$ and a constant term.
In this case all you have to do is to let $t=x^2$ and solve the auxiliary equation.

However, if you interested in using Horner's algorithm, you first need to identify the zeros of the function. To do so, you need to use the **rational root theorem**, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) in case you don't know it. This solves our problem for any rational root. Nonetheless, we still have a problem for any other root. For that, this [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersMethod.html) will give you the method to work those out using Horner's rule.